# How to parse json string into key value pairs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Unable to parse json string

I have got the following hard coded json. I tried converting it to dictionary and parse it but Im unable to do so.

```
NSString *hcResponse  = @"{\"status\":1,\"value\":\"Successfully Login\"}";
```

How to parse such a json into key value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've figured it by myself

```
//convert the string to nsdata
NSData *jsonData = [hcResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
//convert the data to json dictionary
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```